# bezierPathWithRoundedRect: -- odd rendering artefact

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbezierpath

I am drawing a simple rectangle with a few rounded corners:

```
UIBezierPath * p = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:outline
                                         byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight
                                               cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(8, 8)];
```

Oddly enough the top left hand corner seems incomplete - a small notch is missing:

[image: Image that shows the flaw in the top left hand corner]

Strangely enough - if add a `[p close]` - that problem goes away. Now the documentation suggests that:

> This method creates a closed subpath, proceeding in a clockwise
>   direction (relative to the default coordinate system) as it creates
>   the necessary line and curve segments.

so I am wondering where things go wrong ?  Am I misunderstanding the documentation - or is there a subtle bug/issue in my code ?

For completeness the offending code is

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
CGRect outline = CGRectInset(self.bounds, 4, 4);
UIBezierPath * p = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:outline
                                         byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight
                                               cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(8, 8)];
// [p closePath];
[[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
[p setLineWidth:4];
[p stroke];
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the final path isn’t actually closed, which might be a bug (worth [filing](https://bugreport.apple.com) if so)—basically, since it doesn’t know the beginning and end points are connected, you’re seeing end caps (which [by default](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/index.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/kCGLineCapButt) are drawn only to the exact end of the path) rather than a continuous line. It sounds like your `-close` solution works; go with that.